# Problem comparing keys in Appengine/Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key, if-statement

I'm trying to create a relationship between "tables" with Appengine/Python. Imagine I have a "table" for items, and a table for colors. I save the color of an item by saving the color key as an atribute of the item.

That's working well, but this particular piece of code is not working:

```
<select id="colorKey" name="colorKey">
  {% for color in colors %}
    <option value="{{ color.key }}"{% if color.key = item.colorKey %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
      {{ color.name }} - {{ item.colorKey }} - {{ color.key }}
    </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Since the {{ item.colorKey }} and {{ color.key }} variables are actually the same chain of characters, I only can think in a problem with the types.

{{ item.colorKey }} is a string for sure. But maybe {{ color.key }} is not?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. `color.key` probably refers to an instance of the `Key` class. `{% ifequal %}` tries to compare a string with a Key object and the condition is never met.

Django automatically casts this object into a string when you're using `{{ color.key }}` but you have to provide `{% if equal %}` with an actual string.

You can declare a new property in your `Color` class that returns the key as string and then use it with `{% if equal %}`

```
class Color(db.Model):  
    ...
    @property
    def keyasstring(self):
        return str(self.key())
```

Then in your Django template:

```
{% ifequal color.keyasstring item.colorKey %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% if color.key = item.colorKey %}
```

One too few `==`?

Comment: You might need to use `{% ifequal color.key item.colorKey %}` -- I'm not sure which version of Django ships with App Engine.

Comment: It looks like == is new in the latest development version -- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

Comment: BTW, if I try {% if color.name = "Blue" %} then, the if works

Comment: but if I try {{ if color.key = "agpjaG9yZXN0b3AlcgwLEgRUZWFtGKuZAgw" }} the if fails, so color.key is not a string... but what type is it?

Comment: I just discovered that color.key is an object, not a string. Since I cannot find a way to convert the object in a string, I decided to use the color.name as a reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't support arbitrary expressions in 'if' tags (or anything else for that matter). You need to use the 'ifequal' tag - see [the docs](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/) for details.

Comment: true only for legacy django, current templates do have support for comparison operators